# Run multiple android app instances like parallel space

Tags: android, virtualization, whatsapp, multiple-accounts, android-for-work

I want to know how parallel space 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl&hl=en is working. It is an app for logging in with another facebook, whatsapp etc account. You can find the detailed description in the play store link.

I have looked at the folders that parallel space is creating using ES Explorer. They have created the following folder parallel_intl/0/

In this folder they have DCIM, Pictures etc folder. I logged in another whatsapp account using parallel space and they created the whatsapp folder at the following location  parallel_intl/0/Whatsapp

Is it possible to achieve the same thing with Android For Work Container???

Are they some how creating a separate space where Whatsapp etc will run???

Kindly provide some guideline explaining how this can be achieved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Actually they have created a virtual OS  named multi-droid where you can run any app on that OS. As you install any app on their OS the space for that app increases by the size of the app. Firstly they find the path of your installed APK then they copy that APK into somewhere in the directory 
Thus they have the APK to install . now they run it on their OS and they took all the permissions required by the app that way all the permission could be obtained .then the app has a service running in background so notifications can be obtained .