# How to create a virtual sandbox environment in android?

Tags: android, clone

I have been trying to develop an android application which can create multiple instances of a selected application installed on the phone. Usually, if I create multiple accounts on the phone, a replica is made available to the different accounts. I don't want to create a new account. So far, I have only drawn blanks while searching for it. Can someone point me in the direction to search?

Comment: Are you talking about something like Android for Work: https://www.android.com/work/ where there can be a Personal app and a Work app?

Comment: @MorrisonChang Yes I am trying to achieve something like this for versions lesser than 7.

Comment: So from this: https://support.google.com/work/android/answer/6174145 it seems like Android 5.0+ is supported. Check here: https://developers.google.com/android/work/overview and https://developers.google.com/android/work/build-dpc for more info.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I was actually trying to achieve this kind of functionality-
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lbe.parallel.intl

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37006365/run-multiple-android-app-instances-like-parallel-space