# Application INSIDE my Application in Android

Tags: android

How to open any application INSIDE my application, like parallel space opens cloned apps in own window.

I want to open any application without without starting a separate window.

Comment: There is nothing built into Android for this, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You can lunch other app from your app. but you can't open the other app inside your app

Comment: I sad like p. space or virtual xposed, but without cloning

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39443721/11880323

> Actually they have created a virtual OS named multi-droid where you can run any app on that OS. As you install any app on their OS the space for that app increases by the size of the app. Firstly they find the path of your installed APK then they copy that APK into somewhere in the directory Thus they have the APK to install . now they run it on their OS and they took all the permissions required by the app that way all the permission could be obtained .then the app has a service running in background so notifications can be obtained .